# VB.NET Read Binary File into array of structures

Tags: arrays, vb.net, structure, binaryfiles

I've tried using the BinaryReader, but that is definitely not working. It's pretty much stuffing up at the first reader.Readx bit.

So, I've changed tack and am trying to use FILEOPEN, FILEGETOBJECT, FILEPUTOBJECT.

This is working for the first "Record", but from then on, I'm getting

"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt"

Here's the code so far:

```
Dim iFreeFile As Integer = FreeFile()
Dim iFileLength As Integer

' open the file
iFreeFile = FreeFile()
FileOpen(iFreeFile, inFilePath, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Default)
iFileLength = FileLen(inFilePath)

' This bit reads the data
Dim recordLength As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(outValue)
Dim myBytes As Byte() : ReDim myBytes(recordLength)

FileGet(iFreeFile, myBytes, inRecordCount)
BuildStr(myBytes, outValue.GetType, outValue)
inRecordCount += 1
```

outValue is one of several Structures

```
''' <summary>
''' ' Marshal the Byte Array to the Structure
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Buff">Array of Bytes</param>
''' <param name="MyType">Type of the Structure</param>
''' <param name="outBuffer">Structure Object</param>
Private Sub BuildStr(ByVal Buff() As Byte,
                     ByVal MyType As System.Type,
                     ByRef outBuffer As Object)
    ' Marshal the Byte Array to the Structure

    Dim MyGC As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(Buff, GCHandleType.Pinned)
    'Marshals data from an unmanaged block of memory 
    'to a newly allocated managed object of the specified type.
    outBuffer = Marshal.PtrToStructure(MyGC.AddrOfPinnedObject, MyType) ' <----- here we get the error
End Sub
```

The myBytes array loads fine from the FileGet instruction.  The outValue is passed ByRef.

What might be causing this error?

I was having a think last night, do I have to close and reopen the file everytime I read a record?

Answer (score 0):

In descending order of how likely it is to get the methods to work easily:

**Option 1** Write a small program in VB6 to write the data in a more universal format, say XML. This will then be less difficult to read in VB.NET.

**Option 2** Use the [FileGet Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3acfheek.aspx) in VB.NET. Definitely read all the remarks in that documentation and refer back to how the VB6 code wrote the data in the first place. If it turns out that FileGet doesn't work with Option Strict On (which I assume you are using), then put the class which reads the file in a separate class file so that you can use Option Strict Off for that one class.

**Option 3** Read the file in one go into an array of bytes and parse that. [How Visual Basic 6 Stores Data](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_misc/algorithms/article.php/c7495/How-Visual-Basic-6-Stores-Data.htm) might be useful ***if*** VB6 stores data to disk in the same way it stores it in RAM.

---

Also, you should structure your filestream and reader usage as follows to make sure everything is disposed of tidily:

```
Using oFS As New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Using oBR As New BinaryReader(oFS)

    ' reading code goes here

    End Using
End Using
```

P.S. Comparitave->Comparative.

Comment: Re the PS, yes I know, it was someone else's code (and spelling) that I'm converting, they are dislexic and have a serious problem with spelling, makes life searching for words difficult to say the least!

Thanks for the tips, I'll peruse the documentation and have a go...